# Vue.js - How to remove hashbang #! from url?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How to remove hashbang `#!` from url?

I found option to disable hashbang in vue router documentation ( http://vuejs.github.io/vue-router/en/options.html ) but this option removes `#!` and just put `#`

Is there any way to have clean url?

Example:

NOT: `#!/home`

BUT: `/home`

Thanks!

Answer (score 630, accepted):

In **Vue 3**, you'd want to use `createWebHistory` for the `history` option.

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  // ...
})
```

In **Vue 2**, you'd want to set `mode` to `'history'`.

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  // ...
})
```

Make sure your server is configured to handle these links, though.
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: Thanks Bill here you can remove hashbang false too here is the code: `const router = new VueRouter({
 history: true
})`

Comment: I was playing with https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews and adding `{history: true}` works for first page, but the rest of the routes failed.

Comment: You mean when you reload the app on other routes? If so, you need to configure your server properly.

Comment: Please make vue.js 2 information be at the beginning of answer

Comment: Would this code go in index.js of the Router folder or in the main App.vue?

Comment: It goes in whichever file you set `new VueRouter` in. If you're using vue-cli it's in `src/router/index.js`, though.

Comment: This server code from the link doesn't work for me (IIS 10 server)

Comment: can this be used for cli 3?

Comment: I wonder if it should be `new Router()` instead of `new VueRouter()`

Comment: That doesn't exist in Vue 3 ?

Comment: For me it is answered correctly though confusing (concerning vue3).  
The first line states to use `createWebHistory`, which for works for me perfectly.  
The following code snippet on the other hand uses `createWebHashHistory()` which is using the `#` character which I do not want to use nor the results.

Answer (score 119):

For vue.js 2 use the following:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history'
})
```

Comment: What is the difference between this answer and accepted answer here?

Comment: The accepted answer was edited after realizing this was the solution, you can check the edit log of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 52):

For Vue 3, change this :

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
});
```

To this :

```
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});
```

Source : https://next.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#hash-mode

Comment: ... and this import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

Answer (score 35):

Hash is a default vue-router mode setting, it is set because with hash, application doesn't need to connect server to serve the url. To change it you should configure your server and set the mode to HTML5 History API mode.

For server configuration this is the link to help you set up Apache, Nginx and Node.js servers:

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Then you should make sure, that vue router mode is set like following:

**vue-router version 2.x**

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

To be clear, these are all vue-router modes you can choose: "hash" | "history" | "abstract".

Answer (score 32):

For Vuejs 2.5 & vue-router 3.0 nothing above worked for me, however after playing around a little bit the following seems to work:

```js
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  hash: false,
  routes: [
  ...
    ,
    { path: '*', redirect: '/' }, // catch all use case
  ],
})
```

note that you will also need to add the catch-all path.

Answer (score 16):

Quoting the docs.

> The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to
> simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL
> changes.
>
> To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which
> leverages the history.pushState API to achieve URL navigation without
> a page reload:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

> When using history mode, the URL will look "normal," e.g.
> http://oursite.com/user/id. Beautiful!
>
> Here comes a problem, though: Since our app is a single page client
> side app, without a proper server configuration, the users will get a
> 404 error if they access http://oursite.com/user/id directly in their
> browser. Now that's ugly.
>
> Not to worry: To fix the issue, all you need to do is add a simple
> catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any
> static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app
> lives in. Beautiful, again!

Answer (score 13):

```js
window.router = new VueRouter({
   hashbang: false,
   //abstract: true,
  history: true,
    mode: 'html5',
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
  transitionOnLoad: true,
  root: '/'
});
```

and server is properly configured
In apache you should write the url rewrite

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Answer (score 10):

Several good descriptions above lead me into rabbit hole until I realized the "createWebHistory" which replaces "createWebHashHistory" exists in two places in the router/index.js file.  Once in the definition of the constant at the end of the file and again on the import from vue-router at the top of the file.

Found down at the end of the router/index.js file

```
  const router = createRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    history: createWebHistory(),
    // history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes
  })
```

First line in router/index.js file

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
// import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'
```

Now it works like a charm, thank you all above that lead me down this path to success!

Answer (score 5):

The `vue-router` uses `hash-mode`, in simple words it is something that you would normally expect from an achor tag like this.

```html
<a href="#some_section">link<a>
```

To make the hash disappear

```js
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
  },
] // Routes Array
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history', // Add this line
  routes
})
```

`Warning`: If you do not have a properly configured server or you are using a client-side SPA user may get a `404 Error`
if they try to access `https://website.com/posts/3` directly from their browser.
[Vue Router Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Answer (score 4):

Just replace createWebHashHistory with createWebHistory in router.js file

Answer (score 2):

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [...]
})
```

And if you are using AWS amplify, check this article on how to configure server: [Vue router’s history mode and AWS Amplify](https://medium.com/@denis.dmitriyeff/vue-routers-history-mode-and-aws-amplify-762c29fdb6df)

Answer (score 2):

You should add mode history to your router like the below

```js
export default new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes: [
    {
     ...
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The default mode for vue-router is hash mode - it uses the URL hash to simulate a full URL so that the page won't be reloaded when the URL changes.
To get rid of the hash, we can use the router's history mode, which leverages the `history.pushState` API to achieve URL navigation without a page reload:

```js
import {routes} from './routes'; //import the routes from routes.js    

const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: "history",
});

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    render: h => h(App)
});
```

> routes.js

```js
import ComponentName from './ComponentName';

export const routes = [
   {
      path:'/your-path'
      component:ComponentName
   }
]
```

[Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html)

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in src->router->index.js

At the bottom of this file:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  routes,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Vue 3**, you can use **createWebHistory** module provided by the package **vue-router** to get a clean URL.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  // ...
})
```

There is also another module that keeps '#' symbols in the URL named **createWebHashHistory**, which helps the browser navigate to a particular element.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  // ...
})
```

You might prefer to use **createWebHistory** over **createWebHashHistory**, if you want no '#' symbols in the URL.

For more information feel free to check their docs:
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router';
const router = createRouter({
history: createWebHistory(),
routes: [],
});


export default router;
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?