# want to remove '#!/' from url after public in laravel-5.4 with vuejs-2

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.4

I'm using laravel-5.4 with Vue.js-2.
My url's are like this -> http://localhost/abhishek/cinego/public/#!/movie/list... 
I want to remove '#!/' after public in the url. please help. I'm new to vue

Comment: try this `const router = new VueRouter({
 mode: 'history'
})`. Set mode to history in the Router object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove hashbang from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623833/how-to-remove-hashbang-from-url)

Comment: @Pradeepb this code doesn't work for me, thanks anyway

`const router = new VueRouter({
      mode: 'history'
});`

Comment: @chintankotadiya thanks for the suggestion. I'll try all the solution and hopefully one of them work for me

Comment: @sayan0020  which version of vueJs are you using?

Comment: This is in my package.json

  `  "vue": "^1.0.26",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.3.3",
    "vue-html-loader": "^1.2.3",
    "vue-loader": "^8.5.2",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.2",
    "vue-router": "^0.7.13",
  `
Thanks in advance, i'm really new to vue, so please bare with me.

Comment: Ah ok. I thought you were using latest version. Try `var router = new VueRouter({
  history: true
});`.

Comment: @Pradeepb sorry to say no luck, when i use this `const router = new VueRouter({ history: true });` my .vue files are not loading at all.

Comment: How are you defining your routes? Could you post that in the question as well?