# How to remove hashtag(#) from vue-router URL?

Tags: vue.js

I want remove hashtag(#) from urls, but also i need to save no-reload mode. Can i do that?


I have: `page.com/#/home`
I want: `page.com/home`


I tried `mode: 'history'`, but page reloads with it. 
UPD: Is it possible to create SPA app without page reloading and with normal URLs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove hashbang from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623833/how-to-remove-hashbang-from-url)

Comment: (`mode:history` is right; did you also do the serverside configuration described [here](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html)?)

Comment: @DanielBeck Doesn't `mode:history` reload the page even if i configurate it?

Comment: What do you mean by `no-reload` mode? History mode just changes the URL without a hash. If you then manually reload the page, you will see a 404, because the browser actually requests that generated URL. Therefore, you need to configure your server to provide the `index.html` of your SPA on every URL of your server.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 as I wrote, I dont want to page reloading when I'm navigating in my website.  For example, if I'm trying to go `page.com/home` from `page.com/about`, I want to do it without reloading the page.

Comment: How do you go from `/home` to `/about`? Using a regular `<a>` link?

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 i have used regular <a> to do it  and it works(without reloading the page), but with /#/ in url name. My question - how to do it without #(and also without reloading). Is it possible?

Comment: You shouldn't route with native `<a>` tags from one route to another. This works only with a `#` and only because of the original behavior and handling of the fragment identifier by a browser. See my answer.

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked as a search term (on social media networks). It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Most things that use a hash symbol are not hashtags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When activating the history mode, you need to first configure your server according to [the documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html). The reason for that is, that the history mode just changes the URL of the current page. When the user actually reloads the page, he'll get a `404` error, because the requested URL is not actually there. Reconfiguring the server to serve always the main `index.html` of your SPA resolves this issue.

When using a `#` in the URL (no history mode), the browser tries to navigate to the element with the ID, which was given after the `#` (within the same document). This was the original behavior of the fragment identifier. Therefore, if you add a link to your HTML with such a fragment identifier, the browser won't reload the page but actually look for the ID inside the document. The vue-router watches this change and routes you to the correct route. This is the reason it works with hashes. If you just add a regular URL to the HTML, the browser's native behavior is to actually navigate to this page (hard-link). This leads to your experienced reload effect.

The way to handle this, is, to never use regular links to route within a Vue Single-Page-Application. Use the tag `<router-link>` for routing between one page and another (but only within the SPA). This is the way to go, no matter if the browser allows the navigation with `#` without reloading or not. Here is the documentation for the recommended routing tag: [link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html)

You can also route from one route to another programmatically. Use `$router.push()` for that. Here is the documentation for that: [link](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/navigation.html)