# Laravel 5.6 & vue.js router 404

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5.6

I'm updating my laravel website to vue spa, I have just 2 routes in vue at the moment for test purpose.

When click of terms link from page, it works fine and render the component.

But as I refresh /terms page app throws the 404 error.

Any guess what is going on.

routes.js

```
  import Home from './components/Home.vue';
  import Terms from './components/Terms.vue';

  export const routes = [
      {
          path: '/',
          component: Home
      },
      {
          path: '/terms',
          component: Terms
      }
  ];
```

app.js

require('./bootstrap');

```
            import Vue from 'vue';
            import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
            import Vuex from 'vuex';

            import {routes} from './routes';
            import StoreDate from './store';
            import MainApp from './components/MailApp.vue';


            Vue.use(VueRouter);
            Vue.use(Vuex);

            const store = new Vuex.Store(StoreDate);

            const router = new VueRouter({
                routes,
                mode: 'history'
            });


            /**
             * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
             * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
             * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
             */

            Vue.component('tasks', require('./components/Tasks.vue'));

            const app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                router,
                store,
                components: {
                    MainApp
                }
            });
```

Following this video guide
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6FSa6XET8MY

Comment: This is how the history mode behaves. It just changes the URL without requesting the content from the URL. On a reload it does exactly that and the page is not available. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47617576/3233827

Comment: but converting mode to hash did work, I will research the difference mode: history/hash

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the terms route in Laravel too, or return your spa view on 404 in Laravel web routes

Comment: I dont think so that's correct, SPA routes must not depending on Laravel routes, as I understand.

Comment: True, I added the following to my app to get all routes not matching my laravel routes:

`Route::get('{spa?}', function ($spa = null) {
    return view('app');
})->where('spa', '.*');`