# Pound sign on vue router links

Tags: vue.js

Hi how can I remove the pound sign in the router links in vue. I always get a pound sign in every links for example: http://localhost:8080/#/

```js
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'SplashScreen',
      component: SplashScreen
    },
    {
      path: '/aboutus',
      name: 'AboutUs',
      component: AboutUs
    },
    {
      path: '/aboutus',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: Dashboard
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: That's the normal behavior, it is the way SPA (single page application) works. The "pound" sign means that the links will not move the application to other page.

Comment: is there a way to remove it?

Comment: will it not affect if I put an API request on it

Comment: what is your api url example ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove hashbang from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623833/how-to-remove-hashbang-from-url)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use mode as `history`

```
 const router = new VueRouter({
   mode: 'history',
   routes: [...]
 })
```

Also need server configuration `Apache`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

check more details [here](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations)

Comment: Worth noting that this requires server-side configuration to work correctly

Comment: I know but sometimes people don't follow links in answers ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this. I had deployed my vuejs app on heroku already and later changed the mode to history so I can get rid of the pound sign but I'm not sure how to override this server setting on heroku. The doc suggested using .htaccess or apache_app.conf but none of those work I still get 404 when redirecting to other pages. A nudge in the right direction will be highly appreciated