# how to make a 'history mode' push in vuerouter?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

i'm using router.push to change the route,it works,but:

```
router.push({path:'xxx'}
```

the result in my browser shows that, this is a '#(hash) mode push', the address look like:

```
localhost:8080/index/xxx#
```

how can i make a push without #(hash),like this:

```
localhost:8080/index/xxx
```

i have already set mode:'history' in 'router.js'

```
const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: proc...
```

sorry my bad English

here is my code:

methods: {

```
changeIdx (item) {

    console.log(
        this.currentURL.slice(0, this.currentURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + this.urlStore[item]
    )

    this.$router.push(
        this.currentURL.slice(0, this.currentURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) + this.urlStore[item]
    )

}
```

in console:
[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVZzE.png)

in browser:
[address in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YkULP.png)

Comment: That seems like a bug in your code. Can you create a fiddle in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623833/how-to-remove-hashbang-from-url