# VueJS without history mode in Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

In this article ([Vue.js - How to remove hashbang #! from url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623833/vue-js-how-to-remove-hashbang-from-url)), teach how to remove # from URL.

I'm making an application that need to have # in URL, but when I access a route for the first time, don't load (or don't change the content), but if I refresh, the page load successfully.

EDIT1: I forgot to share my Vue Router.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
//import axios from 'axios'

import ListComponent from '../pages/ListComponent'
import Formulario from '../pages/Formulario'

const BASE_URL = process.env.VUE_APP_FRONT_SET_URL;
console.log(BASE_URL);

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
       mode: 'hash',
    routes:[

        {
            path: '/formulario',
            name: 'formulario',
            component: Formulario
        },

         {
            path: '/:nr_atendimento' ,
            name: 'list',
            component: ListComponent
        },
    ]
})
```

And no. console don't show any errors.

Comment: You need to post the vue router configuration (how you set up the router). Did you check the browser console for errors?

Comment: like ssc-hrep mentioned, please share your vue-router file. You should add `mode: 'hash'` to add explicit the hash in the url.

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated.