# Why am I getting this weird behavior with vue router hash mode?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a vue project and the router is behaving weird:

I use a

```
<router-link to="/page" />
```

I use hash mode
I use vuejs 2

I expect /#/page
I get /page#/

what am I doing wrong?

Best regards.

Comment: What does your route definition look like?

Comment: I think you should look at this first :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34623833/vue-js-how-to-remove-hashbang-from-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've Made a mistake, in this particular Case I was NOT using router-link, but a normal anker, didn't See that. That resulted in weird behavior. Thanks for all